# Accessing HBase table - Normal java vs MR job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Please let me know when to use MR job and when to use normal java to access HBase table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to use MR in case you need to perform multiple scans or full table scans. In other words when you need to work with distributed segments in different regions. But, let's say you need you know start row and stop row, so you can query data with single scan (of course not single full table scan), then you can do that directly via Java API. I hope it was useful. And definitely, check out Spark. I think nowadays it is much more convenient than MR.